# Move all Home ViewController Segues to New Controller?

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I want to experiment with another Home view controller on my iPhone app.  Is there an easy way to copy or move all the segues that are on the original controller to the new controller.  The original segues are on a UITableViewController so they are fired manually.  As you can see, I've got quite a few and I don't want to redrag them ... again.  Here's the code and a [diagram](http://www.h4labs.com/design1.html) to give you some idea .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL isPhone = YES;
    DLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    id navController;

    NSArray *sectionTitles = sectionValues[indexPath.section];
    NSString *title = sectionTitles[indexPath.row];

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        navController = _parentController;
    } else {
        navController = self;
        isPhone = NO;
    }
    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Study"]) {
        DLog(@"\n\nWARNING: Need to invoke prepareForSegue");
//        [_parentController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"StudyListSegue" sender:self];
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"StudyListSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Quiz"]) {

        _quizType = 1;
        if (isPhone) _parentController.quizType = 1;
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"QuizListSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Audio Quiz"]) {

        _quizType = 2;
        if (isPhone) _parentController.quizType = 1;
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"QuizListSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Home"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HomeSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Flashcards"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FlashcardListSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Conjugator"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ConjugationListSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Dictionary"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DictionarySegue" sender:self];


    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Numero Practicas"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Numbers2Segue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Juego de Memoria"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ConcentrationListSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Sopa de Letras"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GameListSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Juego el Ahorcado"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HangmanListSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Scores/Retest"]) {
        if (isPhone) {

            [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ScoreSegue" sender:self];

        } else {

            [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"iPadScoreSegue" sender:self];

        }

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Missed Questions"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MissedQuestionSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Options"]) {
        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OptionsSegue" sender:self];

    } else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Help"]) {

        [navController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HelpSegue" sender:self];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I found is to simply to copy the existing controller then past it into the storyboard. Next change the class on the new controller.  All of the segues are brought over when you copy the existing controller.